# assigning php variable value from html table cell

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, variables

I am trying to make a table which displays logs for users that have logged in to the system.
The logs are working perfectly,but i want the tables on the final table column to lead me to the member's information.
Assigning the member id column value for individual rows so i can use them as 'WHERE' in the queries is the problem

Note
The member_id column is a foreign key that links to the member information table
the member details on the other hand are in another table where the member_id is a primary key
The buttons should take me to the member's information using the member_id of the table row that the button is in

```
echo "<table border = 2>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

echo "<tr>
         <td>Member ID</td>
         <td>Date</td>
         <td>Time</td>
         <td>Member Info</td>
   </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
  echo "<tr>
          <td>" . $row['member_id'] . "</td>
          <td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
          <td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>
          <td><input type= 'submit' value = 'Member Information' onsubmit ='memberinfo.php'></td>
           //this button is the one to open member information
</tr>";
}

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

mysql_close(); 
 ?>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: Border attribute is deprecated in `<table>`. Use CSS instead. Also, use quotes to enclose all attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to pass the member ID to memberinfo.php using:

```
echo "<tr>
<td>" . $row['member_id'] . "</td><td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>
<td><a href='memberinfo.php?id=" . $row['member_id'] . "'>Member Information</a></td>
</tr>";
```

Do not use multiple submit button in same page (submit button should work within form tags only). Hyperlink is more suitable in your case.

Note: Of course your `memberinfo.php` needs to fetch the member ID from `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<td><input type= 'submit' value = 'Member Information' onsubmit = 'memberinfo.php'></td>
```

Would this do?

```
<td><a href='memberinfo.php?id=<?php echo $row['member_id'];?>'>Member Information</a></td>
```

You'd them need to handle $_GET['id'] on memberinfo.php to pull the correct record and do whatever.   You'd maybe need to style the link appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
 <td><input type= 'submit' value = 'Member Information' 
     onsubmit ='memberinfo.php'></td>
```

to

```
 <td><input type= 'button' value = 'Member Information' 
     onclick ='memberinfo.php?id=".$row['id']."'></td>
```

You could get the value by using `$_GET['id']` in memberinfo.php. As far as passing the date and time is concerned you could store it in the session and later unset it after transferring the values to variables in memberinfo.php.